# What does it refer to in the context?

Tags: pronouns

The original text:

> [...] For them the working hours are never long enough. Each day is a
>   holiday, and ordinary holidays, when they come, are grudged as
>   enforced interruptions in an absorbing vocation. Yet to both classes,
>   the need of an alternative outlook, of a change of atmosphere, of a
>   diversion of effort, is essential. Indeed, **it** may well be that
>   those whose work is their pleasure are those who most need the means
>   of banishing **it** at intervals from their minds.

What does the first "**it**" refer to here? I think the second "**it**" refer to "work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the second *it* refers to "work". The first *it* is a [**dummy pronoun**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) - this *it* does not refer to an [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)). The *it*s in the following phrases are dummy pronouns:

> It may well be that ...
>
> It is possible that ...
>
> It is probable that ...
>
> It is the case that ...
>
> It is true that ...
>
> It is obvious that ...
>
> It is clear that ...

In each of these examples, *it* does not refer to anything. This type of construction - "It may well be that [statement]" - is equivalent to "[statement] may well be". But it* is sometimes more natural to use a dummy pronoun.

*see what I did there? You could also say: "Using a dummy pronoun is sometimes more natural."

Comment: Is  "[statement] may well be" a complete sentence? It seems to me it's missing a predicative after the linking verb. I have no diffcult to undertand "it" as a dummy pronoun in your other sentence examples as they are all in the form of "It be predicative + [statement]."

Comment: I think I got it now. It seems it needs a little bit tweak in meaning, "It may well be" is equivalent to "It may be highly possible." Here is an example using the same pattern: **It may well be that the information is not available.** at https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/may-very-well-easily

Comment: @Charlie yes, I think it is a complete sentence - if you say (to use a simple example) "That may well be" it's understood to mean "That may well be so" or "That may well be true" or "That may well be the case" (etc). A common use case is contrasting two potential opposite situations, e.g. "John doesn't think this is a natural phrase, but it very well may be." And I agree - "may well be" is like "may be highly possible"!